# Hide Div if another is present jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to simply hide a div if another is present on the page, thought it was going to be straight forward but having some issues.

Hide the div with the class of desc if the div of thanks is visible

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="desc">
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>

    <div class="thanks">
        <h1>thanks</h1>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if($('.thanks').length > 0) {
    $('.desc').hide();
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QejuS/

Comment: jquery is missing in the fiddle

Comment: Yup. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/QejuS/4/

Comment: Works for me with jQuery on fiddle. Are you sure you imported it on your page ? Check for javascript errors in console.

Comment: Yep. It works properly http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/QejuS/3/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it works and the jsFiddle doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: BTW there's also a difference between a div existing in the code and it being visible on the page. Your title and question seems to confuse the two.

Comment: off topic, give me a break... simple error that I forgot to include the file, on further inspection my link to jquery lib was broken... coding for 15 hours straight bro take your bs comments elsewhere.. to everyone else thank you for pointing out a simple error

Comment: I can read only one 'bs comment' here...

Answer (score 1):

Run script on document load:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.thanks').length > 0) {
        $('.desc').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `JS` file.
Your code is working.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QejuS/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle,

left side panel -> Frameworks & Extensions -> 1st dropdown - select jQuery

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DC8He/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    if ($('.thanks').length > 0) {
        $('.desc').hide();
    }
})
```

*Also don't forget to add the script in a dom ready handler*